# KnockoutJS selectedOptions observableArray object empty in change event

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I've got a select menu with multiple selections enabled.

```
<select id="regions" data-placeholder="Choose a Region..." multiple style="height: 35px;" data-bind="options: availableRegions,selectedOptions: selectedRegions,optionsText: 'name',optionsValue: 'value',event: { change: filterResellersByRegion }"></select>
```

I've bound the select to a json array.  While setting up the data-bind on the select, I wired up an observableArray to the selectedOptions property.  Here's my viewmodel:

```
function ResellersViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.availableRegions = ko.observableArray([{
    'name': 'United States',
        'value': 'united-states'
}, {
    'name': 'Canada',
        'value': 'canada'
}, {
    'name': 'Latin America &amp; the Caribbean',
        'value': 'latin-america-caribbean'
}, {
    'name': 'Europe, Middle East &amp; Africa',
        'value': 'europe-middle-east-africa'
}, {
    'name': 'Asia-Pacific &amp; Japan',
        'value': 'asia-pacific-japan'
}, {
    'name': 'China &amp; North Asia',
        'value': 'china-north-asia'
}]);

self.resellers = [{
    'name': '2S',
        'url': 'http://www.2s.com.br/',
        'urlText': 'www.2s.com.br',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['latin-america-caribbean']
}, {
    'name': 'Abacus Solutions LLC',
        'url': 'http://www.abacusllc.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.abacusllc.com',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}, {
    'name': 'Accunet Solutions, Inc.',
        'url': 'http://www.accunetsolutions.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.accunetsolutions.com',
        'status': 'platinum',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}, {
    'name': 'Accuvant',
        'url': 'http://www.accuvant.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.accuvant.com',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}, {
    'name': 'Activar Soulciones, S.A. de C.V.',
        'url': 'http://www.activar.com.mx/',
        'urlText': 'www.activar.com.mx',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['latin-america-caribbean']
}, {
    'name': 'Adcap Network Solutions',
        'url': 'http://www.adcapnet.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.adcapnet.com',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}, {
    'name': 'Advanced Infraestructure & Security Solutions, SA',
        'url': 'http://www.aiss.com.mx/',
        'urlText': 'www.aiss.com.mx',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['latin-america-caribbean']
}, {
    'name': 'Advanced Systems Group',
        'url': 'http://www.virtual.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.virtual.com',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}, {
    'name': 'AE Business Solutions',
        'url': 'http://www.aebs.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.aebs.com',
        'status': 'platinum',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}, {
    'name': 'Alexander Open Systems',
        'url': 'http://www.aos5.com/',
        'urlText': 'www.aos5.com',
        'status': 'gold',
        'city': '',
        'regions': ['united-states']
}];

self.selectedRegions = ko.observableArray();

self.selectedResellers = ko.observableArray(self.resellers.slice(0));

self.filterResellersByRegion = function () {
    alert(self.selectedRegions.length);
};
}

ko.applyBindings(new ResellersViewModel());
```

As I read the documentation, that array is supposed to be updated as the selections are changed.  I'm using the change event as well.  I'm trying to use the change event to trigger a filter on another json array.  However, the observable I have wired up to selectedOptions never gets data inserted into it.  This can be seen with my alert on the change event which checks the length of the array.  What am I doing wrong?  I have setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njtrentacoste/fzSCw/14/) for this issue, feel free to check it out.  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: As a note you need to use multiple="multiple" to properly work in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the observableArray with the `()` to get its length value.  <strike>I'm not sure why (haven't looked into it) but the `.length` property on an observableArray doesn't update and is always 0.</strike> This is an issue with getting the underlying array's length value with just a property ([source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/4))

```
alert(self.selectedRegions().length);
```

That will get you a result.

Unless there's another need to have that event bound to this element, I'd remove it and deal with subscriptions/computeds to do your filtering on an array.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbJee/) with some notes.

Comment: You are correct in that there was a missing parans, but the length property of an observable array is not always zero.  If you take his original fiddle and add parans the length property in the alert is firing correctly.

Comment: Right.  Maybe I wasn't clear.  `self.selectedRegions.length` is always 0 but `self.selectedRegions().length` will update in their original fiddle's alert.  Here's a modified version of their original to show both `.length` and `().length` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzSCw/15/)).  Steve Sanderson discusses this in the KO Github [source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/4)